# Javascript object that returns key as value?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Is is possible to create a pseudo Object that act like an object but returns any key passed to it as the value?

```
var foo = new pseudoObject()
foo['test'] -> 'test'
food[1] -> 1
foo.something -> 'something'
Object.keys(foo) -> []

foo.next = "string";
foo.next -> 'next'
Object.keys(foo) -> []
```

is it possible?

**for completeness**
I have a translation table that takes in an object and switches all the values based on the object keys for those values..

```
"{{this}} is a {{sentence}}" 

Obj1 = {this: 'that', sentence: 'apple'}
```

The thing is 'this' and 'sentence' are actual values as well. I chose to do that because it makes the sentence more readable as opposed to {{key1}} is a {{key2}} , so It would also like to pass in the object:

```
ObjOrginal = {this:'this',sentence:'sentence'}
```

because then I wouldn't have to change anything.
It's impractical to write this object out, So I was wondering if there could be a way to create such an object.

Comment: A `Proxy` will do this. But really, what do you need this for?

Comment: I don't feel like writing a paragraph as to purpose, would make a difference on the answer to the question

Comment: Yes, it would make a difference. [There's likely a better way to solve whatever problem you're having](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Especially one that also works in pre-ES6 environments.

Comment: And what problem does that pseudo object solve? Where do you use it?

Comment: objOriginal = {this:'this',sentence:'sentence'.......... 2000 extra keys........} or objOriginal = new pseudoObject()

Comment: And where was this `objOriginal` used? Sounds like you're actually looking for a `Set`.

Comment: Instead of writing the object out (or intercepting property accesses to the `Obj1` target with a proxy), you should just use something along the lines of `key in obj ? obj[key] : key` in your templating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ES6 feature. Only supported by FF as of today. But it does what you want.

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name;
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

You can find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a `set` trap for `foo.next = "string";` to do nothing?

Comment: Actually it does nothing for the user since the next call (foo.next) will anyway return "next"

Comment: @Bergi - Oh I get your point. There I need to prevent the property from being created. I'll try it.